# If $f \in L^1$ and $f$ is everywhere strictly positive, then does it follow that $|\widehat{f}(y)| < \widehat{f}(0)$ for $y \neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

As the question title suggests, if $f \in L^1$ and $f$ is everywhere strictly positive, then does it follow that $|\widehat{f}(y)| < \widehat{f}(0)$ for $y \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have $\hat{f}(0)\geq |\hat{f}(y)|$ since 
$$|\hat{f}(y)|= \bigg|\int f(x) e^{-2\pi i xy} dx \bigg| \leq \int |f(x)| | e^{-2\pi i xy}| dx = \int f(x) dx = \hat{f}(0).$$

And for strict inequality observe that 
$$\bigg|\int f(x) e^{-2\pi i xy} dx \bigg|^2 = \bigg(\int f(x)\cos(2\pi xy) dx\bigg)^2+\bigg(\int f(x)\sin(2\pi xy) dx\bigg)^2  \quad (\star)$$
Now we apply Jensen's inequality. Looking at "$f(x) dx$" as our measure, we have 
$$\bigg(\frac{1}{\int f(x) dx} \int \cos(2\pi xy) f(x)dx\bigg)^2 < \frac{1}{\int f(x) dx} \int \cos(2\pi xy)^2 f(x)dx$$
and similarly for the integral with $\sin(x)$.

Note the equality in Jensen's inequality $\phi\left(\frac{1}{\mu(E)} \int_E g d\mu  \right) = \frac{1}{\mu(E)} \int_E \phi(g)d\mu$ holds if and only if $g$ is constant or $\phi$ is linear.

Apply this to $(\star)$, we get 
$$\bigg|\int f(x) e^{-2\pi i xy} dx \bigg|^2<\bigg(\int f(x) dx \bigg)^2.$$

Comment: Why can you apply Jensen's inequality?

Comment: For $f>0$,  $\frac{f(x) dx}{\int f(x) dx}$ is a probability measure.

Comment: Yes, but the integrand needs to be convex.

Comment: $\big(\cdot\big)^2$ is the convex function in the Jensen's inequality

Comment: Ah, you are right.

Comment: Pretty good. You might want to explain the strict inequality in Jensens inequality...

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    |\hat{f}(y)| &= \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-iyx}f(x)dx\right| \\
  & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx \\
  & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx =\hat{f}(0).
\end{align}